# Is there a way to open a tmux window (tab) immediately to the right of the active one?

Tags: tmux

If the current window is numbered 3, then I want a new window at 4, and the current 4 should move to 5, 5 to 6 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

`:new-window -a` does exactly this. Add `bind c new-window -a` to your .tmux.conf to make this persistent for everytime you open a new window with `PREFIX c`.